# Method to determine probability distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am planning an experiment to determine the frequency of a binary variable (valued 1 or 0).

Each day, there are 10,000 new events taking place

Each day, I get to draw 100 randomly out of the new 10,000 and see their outcome (either 1 or 0)

How do I estimate the frequency of 1 and 0 in the population with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the 10000 new events follow the same distribution each day, the estimator obtained with a sample of n=100 will be an estimator of the underlying distribution.

The underlying is a Bernoulli distribution with unknown parameter p, the only parameter for a Bernouilli.

Each day you obtain an estimator of p = (sum of ones in sample of 100)/100. 
This estimators will follow a normal distribution with mean = the real p, and standard deviation sqrt(p*(1-p)/100).

Comment: So let's suppose I have 10 samples, each of 100 each. Can I combine these samples to estimate the population frequency? p = sum of all samples( (sum of ones in sample of 100))/(100*10)

Comment: Yes. You can combine the samples of the same day, and if each day the 10000 new events come from the same distribution, you can also combine the samples of different days.